# Empty queryset is returned on print()

Tags: python, django-views

Would anyone help me find out why this won't work.

```
def return_bulk_books(request):
    book = request.POST.getlist('marked_delete')
    books = Books.objects.filter(id__in = book)
    print(books)
```

`print(books)` returns an empty queryset instead of printing all the items in books as requested.

This is the model.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'return_bulk_books' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      <div class="container text-center text-success">{{ message }}</div>
<table class="layout container">
    <thead>
      <th>Book</th>
      <th>Reg No</th>
      <th>Date of issue</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="select-all"></th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </thead>
  {% for item in all_borrowed %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.book_id.book_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.book_id.reg_no}}</td>
      <td>{{ item.issue_date }}</td>
      <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="marked_delete" value="{{ item.pk }}">
      </td>
      <td name = 'pk'><a onclick="return confirm('This book will be returned to the library. Hit ok to confirm..')" href="{% url 'return_book' item.book_id.pk %}" >Return</a> </td>
      
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
    {% endfor %}
<div class="container text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" id="return_all" hidden="hidden" onclick="return confirm('The selected items will be returned to the library. Are you sure about this???')">Return Selected</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what is the result of printing `request.POST.getlist('marked_delete')` (can't see marked_delete in your form anywhere...?)?

Comment: @thebjorn, added it. I had ommitted some parts of the form... It gives the ID s of the selected books.

Comment: and if you add a line saying `print(request.POST.getlist('marked_delete'))`, what does it say?

Comment: It prints a list of the selected book IDs.. like ['79','67']

Comment: what happens if you replace `books = Books.objects.filter(id__in = book)` with the value printed, e.g. `books = Books.objects.filter(id__in=['79', '67'])` ?  (i.e. is it a problem with the front-end or the back-end -- effectively halving the problem ;-) .

Comment: Printing => books = Books.objects.filter(id__in=['79', '67']) returns empty queryset.. i.e print(books) = <QuerySet []>

Comment: Well that reduces the size of your problem quite a bit, and you now need to figure out why it doesn't find those primary keys, e.g. are they in the database, have you implemented a model-manager that would hide them from you, are you using the right database, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234236/discussion-between-fakemake-and-thebjorn).